# Windows Anaconda Keras Install error

Tags: windows, anaconda, keras

Collecting keras
  Using cached Keras-2.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting tensorflow (from keras)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from keras) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow (from keras)

Answer (score 0):

Your question definitely needs more info, but probably you need to install the right version of tensorflow first.

Keras 2 goes well with tensorflow 1, which goes well with python 3.5. If your anaconda runs python 2 or 3.6, first create a python 3.5 conda environment, and install tensorflow and keras there:

> conda create -n myenv python=3.5 anaconda
>
> activate myenv
>
> (myenv) pip install tensorflow
>
> (myenv) conda install keras